# Insert data at a particular excel cell using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I use an excel sheet (Note: Its a xls file not xlsx) as a template where I have few graphs and images which cover the first half of the sheet.

My requirement is to use this template excel sheet. Open it , and start inserting data (result set from an sql query) at a particular excel cell, for example A8.
Is there a simple and efficient way to edit the excel and save it using pandas?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If not pandas is there any way to achieve this? (except using xlutils )

Comment: I deleted my answer as it turns out that ExcelWriter can only write new files, but not update existing files. [Here](https://hackernoon.com/working-with-spreadsheets-using-python-part-1-380a120387f) is an example of updating an existing file (but they use xlutils).